# cookie lifetime in magento

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

In magento, the value of the cookie life time we set from the admin control panel , is browser dependent.

I set the cookie life time value for my default store configuration scope as 600 seconds.
I want to know if this value is browser dependent. Suppose I login to my store at 10 20 am in firefox and 10 25 am in internet explorer, by using the same login id. Then what will happen after 600 seconds, to both these browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are in most cases tied to the useragent (browser), thus logging into the same account from two different browsers/browser sessions will create two different server-side sessions with each one having it's own expiry time. Some systems don't allow multiple sessions to be started for the same account, but in my experience this is not the case with Magento.

Comment: I tested this in apple ipad, but its not working. i set the cookie life time value to 60 seconds for the default store , but its not get timed out after 60 seconds.
this works perfect in windows and linux machines and the browsers in them.

Comment: in that case check server settings, specifically php.ini settings.

Comment: please specify, which settings should I check in php.ini